# Passing multiple selected value from a Listbox to an Array as parameters in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

Below is my C# code to populate the multi-selected items from the listbox

```
List<string> listCountry = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < lstCountry.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (lstCountry.Items[i]Selected)
   {
       countries = listCountry.Add(lstCountry.Items[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

And I have a line to call the method to run the report with the above parameters:

```
retVal = CR.GetReport(Company, countries);
```

My question is :  What data type should I define for **countries** since it keeps giving me error like "can't implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'" when I define countries as
    string countries = null;
What did I do wrong here?  Please help, thank you very much

Sorry I didn't make it clear enough, I have another the function GetReport() which is defined as

```
public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument GetReport( string      Company,  string countries)
{
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument retVal = new rptReortData();
     ReportLogon rptLog = new ReportLogon();
     rptLog.logon(retVal, "Report");
     retVal.SetParameterValue("P_Country", new string[] { country});
}
```

How do I get the value from the listbox assign to **countries**

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide the name of your function but I guess it's GetReport. It doesn't return any value so you can't assign the retVal. Try the below:

```
CR.GetReport(Company, countries);
```

Comment: I added the function GetReport().  What did I do wrong there ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little puzzled by your question, but I'm guessing that the CR.GetReport function is raising an exception? So your data-type for *countries* depends on that function.

I might make the following change:

```
listCountry.Add((lstCountry.Items[i] == null ? string.Empty : lstCountry.Items[i].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return retVal from your function

```
public CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument GetReport( string      Company,  string countries)
{
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument retVal = new rptResearchDataDownload();
     ReportLogon rptLog = new ReportLogon();
     rptLog.logon(retVal, "Report");
     retVal.SetParameterValue("P_Country", new string[] { country});

    // ADD THIS LINE
    return retVal;

}
```

Also you need convert the list to a string. You can do this like this:

```
countries = listCountry.Aggregate((list, c) => list + c + ",");
```

Comment: Yes, I added that, it works well on that part, thank you very much.  However, the data type of list<string> conflict with countries.

Comment: Hi Bartosz, what is <b>list</b>, it doesn't show up in my VS2010 intelligence after I typed Aggregate

Comment: list is the name of the argument for the lambda expression. You can name it anything you what e.i. 'l' for short.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> listText = new List<string>();
List<string> listValue = new List<string>();
foreach (int index in ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices()) {
    listText.Add(ListBox1.Items[index].Text);
    listValue.Add(ListBox1.Items[index].Value);
}
```